# How would I be able to set slippage for exactInputSingle on Uniswap v3 and Pancakeswap v3?

Tags: web3js, uniswap, web3.py, pancakeswap, uniswapv3

I'm able to do swap transactions using `multicall` and `exactInputSingle` functions on both Uniswap v3 and Pancakeswap v3. However, I have no idea how would I be able to set the slippage. The v2 routers has a `getAmountsOut` function, which makes it possible to set slippage because I would know what is the exact exchange between two tokens in a pool. As for v3, there's no way to check the price and set the slippage.

Edit:
I saw there's a `checkOracleSlippage` function on the "read contract" tab of the Pancakeswap Smart Router v3, but I have no any idea how to use it. I couldn't find any documentations about it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found a way to do this by using the `sqrtPriceX96` in the token's pool address by querying `slot0`. The documentation for this is gone but I've searched and saw other people using this formula:

```
price_ratio = ((sqrtPriceX96**2)/(2**192))*(10**token_decimal/10**18)
```

The ratio and amount was close, but not quite as exact was what I see on Pancakeswap swap page.